# Designing mongo 'schema' for RESTful application

Tags: mongodb, rest, database-schema, nosql

I'm trying to teach myself mongo through writing an application, and I'm struggling with the best way to design the mongo 'schema' (I know it's schemaless, but that is probably the core issue with my understanding in that I'm coming from a relational background)

Anyway, the application is a Gift List manager, where a user can create a Gift List and can add Gifts they would like to receive to their list. Other users can subscribe to the list, and can mark a Gift from the Gift List as claimed/purchased. (So as to prevent the problem of getting duplicate gifts at Christmas!)

At the moment my GiftLists collection is not 'relational' and is simply a collection of GiftList documents with sub documents for the Gifts, like this:

```
{
    "GiftLists": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "55e9924848c4ffd723890b48"
            },
            "description": "Xmas List for Some User",
            "gifts": [{
                "description": "Mongo book"
                "claimed": false
            },
            {
                "description": "New socks"
                "claimed": false
            },
            {
                "description": "New socks"
                "claimed": false
            }],
            "owner": "some.user",
            "subscribers": ["some.other.user", "my.friend"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The idea is that `some.user` is the owner of the Gift List and has added 3 items he would like to receive. `some.other.user` has subscribed to the list and can see the Gift List and it's Gifts. He may choose to buy one of the gifts, so needs to mark it as claimed so that `my.friend` does not also buy it.

At the moment, each Gift in the gifts array is a sub-document without its own id, and I think this is where I'm getting stuck in my understanding/thinking.

I'm trying to provide the app functionality with a RESTful interface.

- To `POST` a new Gift List the url is `/giftList/add` where the request body is the new Gift List
- To `GET` an individual Gift List including the child Gift's the url is `/giftList/<listId>` - eg: `/giftList/55e9924848c4ffd723890b48`

With the above in mind, my natural next step is to be able to mark a Gift as claimed, perhaps with:

- `PUT` to the url `/gift/claim/<giftId>`
  But I don't have any ids on the Gift sub documents

So maybe my url should be:

- `/giftList/<listId>/claim/<giftId>`
  But again, I don't have an id on the Gift sub document

Or maybe I try to use the description of the item

- `/gift/claim/<gift description>` eg: `/gift/claim/Mongo+book`
  But what if more than one person had a Gift List containing 'Mongo book', and URL encoding the characters of the description could be messy

Or maybe I reference the Gift List

- `/giftList/<listId>/claim/<gift description>` eg: `/giftList/55e9924848c4ffd723890b48/claim/New+socks`
  But which instance of 'New socks' am I claiming? (after all, everyone needs lots of new socks for Christmas!)

Or maybe I reference the index of the Gift

- `/giftList/<listId>/claim/<gift index>` eg: `/giftList/55e9924848c4ffd723890b48/claim/2`
  But this feels fragile (as it implies that the list must always be presented in the same sequence)

To me what it really feels like is that I need another collection, just for the Gifts, where each Gift document has its own id, which I can then reference in my RESTful url. And either the Gift has a reference to it's parent GiftList, or the GiftList has an array of references to the Gifts
But this is all a very 'relational' way of thinking ... isn't it ?

What's the best way of doing this? Or, if there is no 'best' way, what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with a new collection, or you could add an unique identifier field to each list entry. The MongoDB solution for unique identifiers is generating an [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), just like those used for the `_id` field of documents. Most MongoDB database drivers should expose functionality for generating ObjectId's. For details, consult the documentation of your database driver.

Comment: Thanks - I think I'm going to go with a new collection, and to manually maintain the references (rather than using DBref) as recommended here http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/database-references/#id4